# How to change content of <script> via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how I could change the content of this Leaflet code,

```
<script id="pdis">
window.onload = function () {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-26.40894, -54.67430], 18);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

        L.marker([-26.40893, -54.67438]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<b>eldorado punto de interes</b><br/> tu chichachicha.").openPopup();

        L.marker([-26.40896, -54.67403]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<b>Eldo punto 1</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

};
</script>
```

Im trying to update those L.markers after a search, like

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$q=$_POST[q];
$con=conexion();

$sql="select * from pdi where name LIKE '".$q."%'";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);

if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0){

echo '<b>No hay sugerencias</b>';

}else{

echo '<b>Sugerencias:</b><br/>';

while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

echo '<img src="logo/'.$fila['id'].'.jpg"></img><br><em>'.$fila['cat'].'</em><br><b>'.$fila['name'].'</b><br>'.$fila['dir'].'<br><a href="msite/'.$fila['id'].'.html" target="_blank">Más...</a>';
}

}

?>
```

First, I dont know if I got to use JQuery's `text()` or `html()`.

Comment: It looks as though you're trying to change the content of the html using php *before* the document is even sent to the browser. Is this correct? Or are you indeed trying to change the document *after* it is sent to the browser?

Comment: If your using php use that to generate the doc with the correct markers, there is no need to change in the browser after load. And this is not possible, but any variable can be over written.

Comment: @enigma the script of the leaflet map is center on a town, with a marker to start, then is a search text-box, its that php code to send Matches, and I want to update those L.markers with the same mysql query

Comment: @AndresBastias It's still not clear exactly what you're trying to do. What do you want to update the L.markers to?

Comment: I will try once more, but thank you anyway @enigma. I want to update that <script> content with a new L.markers' lat-lng information (a $fila['latlng'] from the mysql query). Sure I need a jquery function, sure it has to be html() or text(), but my informal knowledge takes me stuck in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I've interpreted your question is that you want to update the markers on a leaflet map with the coordinates returned from a search.

In order to do this, you should change your current code, to store the markers in accessible variables. Something like

```
var markerA = L.marker([-26.40893, -54.67438]).addTo(map);
var markerB = L.marker([-26.40896, -54.67403]).addTo(map);
```

You can then change the coordinates of the markers using

```
markerA.setLatLng([newLat, newLong]) ;
```

`newLat` and `newLong` need to be returned by your php script in an ajax call. The JavaScript for this will look like

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'search.php',
  data: {q: search_query},
  success: function(data){
    // update a single marker with the first set of returned coordinates
    markerA.setLatLng([data[0].lat, data[0].long]) ;
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

and the php file `search.php` will look something like (changed from your example)

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$q=$_GET[q];
$con=conexion();

$sql="select * from pdi where name LIKE '".$q."%'";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);

$result = array();

while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  // append lat long coords to result array
  $result[] = array('lat' => $fila['lat'], 'long' => $fila['long']);
}

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

apologies if I've made a syntactical error anywhere - this is supposed to be more of an overview than actual code.

Comment: You are such a nice person, thank you for giving me new ideas to work! I cant upvote your answer yet, but Im grateful

Comment: @AndresBastias If the above post has answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the green tick near the voting buttons, but no worries if not. Enjoy coding!